# Video stream freezes after changing aspect ratio or orientation of the stream

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, gopro

I am developing an Android application, where I want to be able to stream live picture from the GoPro camera.
I am able to stream what the GoPro sees, but when I send a command to GoPro to change the aspect ratio of the stream or to flip the stream 180 degree my stream freezes.

I am using `AsynkTask` for the URL GoPro commands so I don't freeze the main UI thread. For the stream I am using the `MeadiPlayer` and the `SurfaceView`.
This is the URL what I pass to the MediaPlayer: http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8

I am implementing both `SurfaceView` callbacks and `MediaPlayer` `onPrepare` listener. When I send a command to the GoPro, for example changing the orientation of the screen by 180 degree while streaming, I first stop the stream. Then when the `AsyncTask` finishes I call `prepareAsynk` of my `MediaPlayer` instance and when `onPrepare` gets called I start the stream again with `start`, but the stream just stays froze.

Then if I call `stop` again following with the `prepareAsynk`, then `start` in `onPrepare` the stream starts playing again.

Anybody has any hint how can I overcome this issue?